# Show that a $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$ is not a star domain

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $K\neq\emptyset$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$ is not a star domain.

---

Let $a\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$ and $c\in K$ be arbitrarily chosen. The point $a$ indeed exists as $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K\neq \emptyset$. Otherwise $\mathbb{R}^n$ would be bounded which is a contradiction.

We define $\psi_a:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$, where
$$\psi_a(t)=a+t(c-a).$$
As $K$ is bounded we find a $t_0>1$, such that $\psi_a(t_0)\notin K$. Let's denote $\psi_a(t_0):=b$ and consider the line segment $S(a,b)$ with $\varphi:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and
$\varphi(t)=a+t(b-a)$. It follows
\begin{align*}
\varphi(t)=a+t(\psi_a(t_0)-a)=a+t(a+t_0(c-a)-a)=a+tt_0(c-a)
\end{align*}
As $\frac{1}{t_0}\in[0,1]$we see that $\varphi\left(\frac{1}{t_0}\right)=c\in K$. As $a \in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$ was arbitrarily chosen I can construct a point $b\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$ for each point $a\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$, such that the line segment $S(a,b)$ contains a point $x\in K$. Hence, $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$ cannot be a star domain.

---

Initially, I was confident that my proof is correct but my tutor told me that I have to use both properties of compactness (i.e. boundedness **and** closeness). Is my proof wrong?

Comment: To me it feels like boundedness indeed suffices.

Comment: Your proof seems good.

Comment: bounded and non-empty suffices